# What stops anybody from copying their ssh public key onto my server?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security

I am setting up my first ever home server and want to make it ssh-able from the internet so i can access it anywhere.

I am following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) and I understand it so far up until where it says

> Once the key pair is generated, it's time to place the public key on the virtual server that we want to use.
>
> You can copy the public key into the new machine's `authorized_keys` file with the `ssh-copy-id command`. Make sure to replace the example
>   username and IP address below.
>
> ```
> ssh-copy-id user@123.45.56.78
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can paste in the keys using SSH:
>
> ```
> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
> ```

I am confused because can't anyone just generate an rsa key on their local computer and then copy it to my server (assuming they know the IP Address or domain name and a username on the server)?

Comment: Yeah you've seen from DanielB's answer.. Also, you have to enable PasswordAuthentication too in order to copy the key over.   Sometimes guides don't explain things well other than what commands to type in.. So the way to learn from a guide is to Do it from the guide. In this case if you tried it you would see that it prompts for a password.

Comment: right, i have one more question though. How is this better than using passwords as someone could just try to brute force method of copying their key over since all you need to copy the key is a password.?

Comment: or is it the case that once you disable PasswordAuthentication in the settings, no more rsa keys can be copied to the server?

Comment: re the brute force. Once the key is copied over then PasswordAuthentication can be set to No. Then ssh-copy-id cannot get in.   In order to get in, ssh-copy-id   will ssh in.  So, if the's source computer's key is not on the destination server and PasswordAuthentication is set to No, then ssh-copy-id can't get in as ssh can't get in either.  ssh  by default tries PubKeyAuthentication first, then PasswordAuthentication. So if the key works it goes in no prompt, and if the key fails then you get a password prompt. And sshd often has PubKeyAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication to yes.

Comment: I am not sure whether ssh-copy-id attempts PubKeyAuthentication, but if it did it'd be pointless. Because if it can get in via the key, then it has nothing to do, and if it can't, it'll have to try PasswordAuthentication anyway.  BTW It is possible for example for ssh to go in specifying to only do PasswordAuthentication `$ ssh -o "PubKeyAuthentication no" user@comp`   Or  PasswordAuthentication no, so it only tries PubKeyAuthentication. By default it tries both i.e. Key then if that fails then Password. And whatever method it tries can only work if sshd_config on the dest computer allows it

Comment: so once PasswordAuthentication is set to no then ssh-copy-id is useless, thus thwarting brute force attackers?

Comment: Yes that's right. Setting PasswordAuthentication No, in sshd_config on the destination machine. That will thwart brute force attackers / dictionary attackers, they won't get the prompt for a password. And nobody tries brute forcing a key(generating keys) 'cos keys are just so long!  By the way, somebody brute forcing would likely use ssh as a tool directly rather than ssh-copy-id, and once they are in they could use ssh-copy-id, but I suppose they could use ssh-copy-id as a tool when brute forcing! But indeed, they'd be thwarted by PasswordAuthentication No.

Comment: awesome! thanks so much for the information! learning server administration one step at a time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding. After running `ssh-copy-id bla@example.com` you’ll get a prompt `Password:`. Without knowing the password or any other valid credentials, the command cannot actually work.

Answer (score 0):

If they could perform the copy operation, then they can already perform other operations as well. So this concern makes no sense.

Comment: Well how do you define who is allowed to copy keys over? I am confused because the entire tutorial seems like you do operations locally on your computer and then suddenly somehow are allowed to copy your key over to the server only needing a username and IP adress

Comment: @user2237160 All non-restricted users (capable of shell or SCP/SFTP access or executing commands) can do it. Why wouldn’t they? They have access anyway. Because to copy the key you need to log in with your previous credentials (other key or password or whatever).

Comment: what do you mean by "to copy the key you need to log in with your previous credentials," the guide never mentioned logging into the server to copy the key over. all it said was you need to do the ssh-copy-id user@serverIPAddress. Are you saying that this command prompts you for the password of 'user'?

Comment: @DanielB has confirmed it. You do need the password. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: His title did say "can't **anybody** copy their ssh public key onto my server?    The answer is No[only those that have the password can.. and when passwordauthentication is enabled).  If anybody could get in then it'd be a problem, so his concern is reasonable given the question he is asking.